# should I track (version control - e.g git, github ) requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipenv, pipenv-install

Im using python 3.7
Im new to python (my main dev experience comes from javascript).
I understand there is a Pipfile who specify the packages Im using directly .
Additionally, there is a Pipfile.lock which specifies exact versions of direct and indirect dependencies (like  yarn\package.lock in js ).
requirements.txt looks like its doing the exact same thing .

Which ones should I track ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pipfile (and Pipfile.lock) are specific to `pipenv`, which is a relatively new tool. Whether you maintain `requirements.txt` depends on whether you want people using your repository to be able to use `pip` directly, rather than using `pipenv` themselves

In general, you should keep both Pipfile and Pipfile.lock under source control. Pipfile.lock is what specifies *exactly* what packages should be installed in the `pipenv`-managed virtual environment for reproducible builds. `Pipfile` is mostly a convenience for generating `Pipfile.lock`.